# Layered Nav not working with Solr

Tags: xml, solr

I set up Solr for my magento site following [this guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-use-the-solr-search-engine-with-magento-enterprise-edition) from magento. The connection works, indexing works, and the search is working well.

The issue is that now my search results have no layered nav. The column just isn't showing up at all. There is a question someone posted who had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547747/magento-layered-navigation-not-working-with-solr), where they suggested editing a line in catalog.xml. However, their "solution" changed nothing for me. Does anyone have any experience with this issue? Does anyone have a catalog.xml file of a Magento installation working fully with solr that is showing layered nav in the results page?

I am on EE 1.14 with Solr 3.6.2.

Comment: `search.xml` replaces the original LN block from Mage_Catalog with one from Enterprise_Search. Hunt in there and see what you find.

Answer (score 0):

This could be absolutely anything. At a guess you have a module rewriting the current layer or layered nav. display and its causing it not to be rendered using the appropriate search engine.

Disable all third party modules, then your theme and check if it then works.

You need to differentiate it being a code/template issue from it being a problem with the data in SOLR itself (sometimes the attributes arent completely populated, causing odd issues).

Comment: I tried disabling all themes and modules before posting this and still had the issue.

Comment: Tried disabling or did disable? Ie. Did you remove the entire contents of community/local? Restore clean copies of core, lib and frontend folder?

Comment: Disabled all on the backend. I did not fully remove all the contents of community and local, nor did I restore a clean core though I've never edited core files

Comment: Disabling on the backend is not sufficient. The module folders need either renaming or removing. Replacing the core/lib/design is merely good practice when debugging